# python program not printing all pickle file data

Tags: python, python-3.x, pickle

```
testdata = {}
testdata[Name] = Score
fileexists = os.path.isfile('TestResults- Class '+classnumber)
if fileexists == False:
    open('TestResults- Class '+classnumber,mode="w+")
    mypicklefile = open('TestResults- Class '+classnumber,mode="wb")
    pickle.dump(testdata,mypicklefile)
    mypicklefile.close()
elif fileexists == True:
    mypicklefile = open('TestResults- Class '+classnumber,mode="ab")
    pickle.dump(testdata,mypicklefile)
def teacher():
    classchoice = input('what class would you like to see?: ')
    readablefile = open('TestResults- Class '+classchoice,mode="rb")
    datafile = pickle.load(readablefile)
    for name in sorted(datafile):
            print(name, datafile[name])
```

I was working on a quiz and was trying to print the data from the quiz. the problem is it will only print one name and one score even if more scores or names exist in the file.

Comment: You should use `if not fileexists:` and `if fileexists:` to test a boolean; using comparison with `==` is error prone (you can easily end up chaining comparisons).

Comment: In this case you don't even need to test if the file exists. *Just use `'ab'`*, it'll create the file if it didn't exist yet.

Answer (score 2):

You are writing **new** pickles to the file by appending. Your loading code only ever loads the **first** pickle, so the first ever entry you created.

You'll need to use `'wb'`, always, to replace the on-disk data with the new version of your dictionary.

There is little point in trying to read the other pickles you wrote to the file by using `'ab'` append-mode; those are later and later revisions of the same dictionary. You'd have to read just the last one, which is inefficient compared to just replacing the whole file each time you updated the dictionary.